# If σ does not have any relation symbols, then h is a σ-embedding if and only if it is one-to-one.

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

Let $A, B$ be $σ$-structures and let $h:A→B$ be a $σ$-homomorphism. Prove that if $σ$ does not have any relation symbols, then $h$ is a $σ$-embedding if and only if it is one-to-one.

Definition 1: A $σ$-embedding is a $σ$-homomorphism  for which $h$ is a $σ$-isomorphism from $A$ to $B’$ with $B’$ being the substructure of $B$ formed by $h[A]$.

Definition 2: A $σ$-isomorphism is a $σ$-homomorphism that has a 2-sided inverse $h^{-1}$, which is also a $σ$-homomorphism.

From those definitions, apparently the rest of the proof is trivial. However I'm not sure... First of all I'm confused about why it only needs to be one-to-one, why not onto? Is it because we excluded the relation symbols for which the property is only one sided?

Comment: You should try to explain the setting you're working on a little better, specially on universal algebras and first-order logic which are not universally well-known. Anyway: It only need to be one-to-one because you only want an isomorphism over $h[A]$, and not over all of $B$. Moreover, $h[A]$ is a substructure of $B$, as it is closed under all constants and functions in your signature. I'm not sure what you mean by a property being "one-sided", so I assume it is only an intuitive explanation, which feels correct IMO.

Comment: The thing that could go wrong with relation symbols is that they wouldn’t be preserved by the inverse. In other words, some elements might be related in the image but their preimages aren’t related.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro What I meant by the property being one sided is exactly what spaceisdarkgreen explained. Thank you both for you explanations and precisions. However I'm still having trouble picturing why h is an embedding iff it is one-to-one.

Comment: @AmélieSte-Marie Yes, that is more-or-less what I meant by an "intuitive explanation". I think intuition is more important than being completely formal at every step (we can always formalize everything in a few years time), and I think the way you are understanding the subject is correct. Try to come up with a few counter-examples for relational structures on your own and see where things go wrong (I like order relations; what order relations can you think of on $\mathbb{N}$ and how do they compare?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $h$ need not be onto for this problem as the definition of an embedding is that it is an isomorphism onto its image $h[A]$. The size of the "ambient" structure $B$ doesn't matter - only how $A$ relates to $h[A]$.

One side of this proof is easier. Suppose that $h$ is an embedding. Then it is an isomorphism onto $h[A]$, i.e. there is an inverse map $h^{-1}: h[A] \longrightarrow A$. Hence, if $h(a_1) = h(a_2)$ then $a_1=h^{-1}(h(a_1))=h^{-1}(h(a_2))=a_2$ and $h$ is one to one. Note here that we didn't need $h^{-1}$ to be a $\sigma$-homomorphism; this works equally well if we forget the $\sigma$-structure and consider these only as sets.

For the converse, suppose that $h$ is one to one. Then I claim that there is an inverse $h^{-1}: h[A] \longrightarrow A$. Indeed, it is not hard to see that there is a set map $h^{-1}$. For any $b \in h[A]$, there is a *unique* element $a \in A$ such that $h(a) = b$. This is precisely the definition of $h$ being one to one. Hence, we can simply define $h^{-1}(b) = a$ for $b \in h[A]$. We are not done yet, however, as we need to show that $h^{-1}$ is in fact a $\sigma$-homomorphism. And here is where we need to use the assumption that $\sigma$ has no relation symbols.

This assumption tells us that $\sigma$ consists solely of function symbols, so indeed let's let $f$ be an $n$-ary function symbol. Consider $h^{-1}(f(b_1, \dots, b_n))$ for $b_i \in h[A]$. Write $h(a_i) = b_i$ for all $i$. Then observe that
$$
\begin{align*}
h(h^{-1}(f(b_1, \dots, b_n))) &= f(b_1, \dots, b_n)\\
&= f(h(a_1), \dots, f(h(a_n)))\\
&=h(f(a_1, \dots, a_n)),
\end{align*}
$$
as we assumed that $h$ was a $\sigma$-homomorphism. Furthermore, as $h$ is one to one, this equation tells us that $h^{-1}(f(b_1, \dots b_n)) = f(a_1, \dots, a_n) = f(h^{-1}(b_1), \dots, h^{-1}(b_n))$. Thus, $h^{-1}$ is a $\sigma$-homomorphism and $h$ is a $\sigma$-embedding. This notation is a bit off in the case where $f$ is a $0$-ary function, i.e. a constant, but the same proof holds.

By the way, I think it's always good practice to try to break the conclusion by breaking the assumptions. That is, if we had relation symbols in $\sigma$ could we find counterexamples to this claim? Here's an example: take $\sigma$ to contain a single binary predicate $P$. Let $A$ and $B$ both equal $\mathbb N$ as sets. For the $\sigma$-structure $A$, we say that $P_A(a_1, a_2)$ iff $a_1 < a_2$. For the $\sigma$-structure $B$ we say that $P_B(b_1, b_2)$ is always true. Then the identity map $id: A \longrightarrow B$ is a $\sigma$-homomorphism and it is one to one, but it is not an embedding. Indeed, the inverse (which is still the identity) does not preserve $P$, as $P_B(1, 0)$ is true but $P_A(1, 0)$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Say we take two $\sigma$-structures $A$ and $B$ and $h\colon A\to B$ an injective $\sigma$-homomorphism.

Then $h(A)$ contains all constants in your signature and is closed under functions in your signature: if $x\in h(A)$, then $x=h(a)$ for some $a\in A$. If $f$ is a function symbol in your signature, then
$$f^B(x)=f^B(h(a))=h(f^A(a))$$
also belongs to $h(A)$.

So how would we go on to prove that the inverse $h^{-1}\colon h(A)\to A$ is a morphism? Well, of course it preserves the interpretation of constants. For a $1$-ary function symbol $f$, we have
$$h\circ f^A=f^B\circ h$$
so composing with $h^{-1}$ both on the left and on the right implies that
$$f^A\circ h^{-1}=h^{-1}\circ f^B$$
which means that $h^{-1}$ is also a $\sigma$-homomorphism. A similar argument holds for general $n$-ary function symbols.

But the problem is that the $\sigma$-homomorphism condition on a relation symbol $R$ (which I assume to be a binary relation just for simplicity) is that
$$(h\times h)(R^A)\subseteq R^B$$,
which only translates to
$$R^A\subseteq (h^{-1}\times h^{-1})(R^B).$$
**The inclusion is on the opposite direction** than the one that would be necessary for $h^{-1}$ to preserve $R$!!! That's where things could go awry.

For an specific example, take the signature $\sigma=(R)$ with only one binary relation symbols. Take your favourite set $X$ with at least two elements, and consider the two interpretations of $\sigma$ as follows:
$$A=(X,\mathrm{eq}),\qquad B=(X,\mathcal{P}(X)),$$
where "$\mathrm{eq}$" is the equality relation on $X$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the  finest relation on $X$ (everyone is related to everyone). Then the identity $A\to B$ is obviously a $\sigma$-homomorphism, but it is not a $\sigma$-isomorphism.